# Team permissions with UAA and BOSH

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa, cf-bosh

I have a Bosh Directory connected to UAA. What I want to do is restrict the access to the Director for teams that should have access only to their releases. Therefore I want to use the Teams in UAA.

Now I have the following problem with UAA and BOSH, following this documentation https://bosh.io/docs/director-users-uaa-perms.html#team-admin:

1. I created a group `bosh.teams.jenkins.admin` with `uaac group add bosh.teams.jenkins.admin`
2. I created a user `jenkinsadmin`with `uaac user add jenkinsadmin --emails mail@test.com`
3. I added the user to the group with `uaac member add bosh.teams.jenkins.admin jenkinsadmin`

Additionally I added

```
scope: openid,bosh.admin,bosh.read,bosh.*.admin,bosh.*.read,bosh.teams.*.admin
```

into the manifest of the BOSH director.

When I now try to upload a bosh release with `bosh upload release` I get the following error message:

```
Error 600000: Require one of the scopes: bosh.admin, bosh.0c5b93a8-46a5-4cb2-81be-b17f97afaf0f.admin
```

I checked the settings of my user with `uaac user get jenkinsadmin` and see the following output:

```
groups:
  -
    value: d6788c74-9d24-4df0-9215-1413ad8c7fed
    display: cloud_controller_service_permissions.read
    type: DIRECT
  -
    value: 0298444a-d9e3-456a-a27b-4fc66d5e41df
    display: openid
    type: DIRECT
  -
    value: 763ae5cc-7d9e-411f-9e08-54850ff9fe44
    display: password.write
    type: DIRECT
  -
    value: a349c0b8-f543-4409-8441-c8a6acdea488
    display: notification_preferences.read
    type: DIRECT
  -
    value: 7bde9588-8d6e-4c51-81f8-c5a4cf71fdd7
    display: cloud_controller.read
    type: DIRECT
  -
    value: ad49d3a5-232f-45fa-917d-f74326674857
    display: uaa.user
    type: DIRECT
  -
    value: 013ed852-59ad-4c88-9c3d-5e397f82f18b
    display: scim.me
    type: DIRECT
  -
    value: 83e5c21e-74c2-412e-a1e9-9a206841b0dc
    display: bosh.teams.jenkins.admin
    type: DIRECT
  -
    value: 09a37162-a999-416b-b1fd-923378aba7d8
    display: notification_preferences.write
    type: DIRECT
  -
    value: 2cd48b42-a0dc-4f60-9ac6-67cf40023726
    display: approvals.me
    type: DIRECT
  -
    value: ad596184-4de8-4b43-8779-1292af4ebe04
    display: oauth.approvals
    type: DIRECT
  -
    value: 3c0df91d-4f70-4320-aa34-01a9651272ee
    display: cloud_controller.write
    type: DIRECT
  approvals:
  active: true
  verified: false
  origin: uaa
  schemas: urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0
  username: jenkinsadmin
  zoneid: uaa
```

So my question is, what do I have to do, to enable the UAA user `jenkinsadmin` to upload a release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BOSH team admins can't upload releases to the director.

See http://bosh.io/docs/director-users-uaa-perms.html#team-admin for the range of permissions this team admins have.

You will need to use a regular admin user for uploading releases.